# How do I make the operator parameters panel appear in the sequence editor instead of the 3d view?

Tags: python, add-on

I have an operator I wrote which adds letterboxing to VSE strips: [letterbox.py](https://github.com/mutantbob/blender-letterbox/blob/master/letterbox.py)

It has some parameters that I would like to expose to the user, but the operator parameters panel only appears in the tool shelf of the 3D view, which is not usually in use when doing VSE work.

How do I get blender to show these operator parameters somewhere that would be accessible to someone using a traditional VSE window layout?

Comment: Check out this tutorial:  After you create your panel, you can make it accessible via Hotkey for a quick popup.
https://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/07/12/creating-custom-toolbar-panel-python-scripting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adjusting options is support, pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> will bring up the operator options in most blender windows.

[image]

Another option may be to setup a panel in the properties sidebar that shows your operator options.